# WPF DataGrid can't reproduce WindowsForms datagrid resizing behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, datagrid

I'm looking over the web to reproduce a behaviour that I used almost every time in windows forms:

Columns resize to allow content to fit, if there isn't enough space a scrollbar appear.
If I, for example, maximize the window which will allow me to have more space than what is required, the columns resize to fill all that space.

How to achieve this? Is this possible?

Comment: The reason this might not be possible has to do with virtualization. If columns 'auto' size to content, they will continually grow/shrink as the user scrolls up and down, which would make for a dodgy user experience.

Comment: I'm sure this was possible in winforms, that's why I'm asking (I used it a lot of times!)

Comment: I noticed now that only rows are virtualized, not columns; maybe can help in some way

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I've seen the Telerik WPF data grid with the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Yea but I can't pay 1000$ for an utility program unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without passing through code, I tested it in thousands ways and I couldn't find a solution without passing through C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Use star Width

```
 <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
```

You can set the priority with the number.

```
 <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
```

the first column is 3 times the second one.

Comment: Where a columndefinition should be placed in datagrid?I'm using DataGridTextColumn at the moment. Also, your answer is not working: In this way columns will try to fit the space available, while I want that a scrollbar appear if all the content can't be shown, and when we have more space they will "fill" that space instead of showing a blank column

Comment: in the Width of the DataGridTextColumn you can use 1* 
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" etc... />

Comment: Read the edit for the previous comment, sorry edited while you were posting.

Comment: As I'm reading around (last 3 hours), it looks like is **not possible** (what microsoft where thinking about?!). You can do it only through code.